# Subversion .tmpl

Tags: svn

OK, here's the question I have with the hooks.  Are the .tmpl meant to run on non-windows PCs that are in the hooks folder and you have to create your own .bat files to run hooks for subversion on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can rename the .tmpl to .bat. The hook scripts need to be executable in windows. You could provide .exe files as well.

The example scripts are pretty basic and shouldn't cause much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Yup.. the `.tmpl` files are samples. You will have to roll your own under windows. I would recommend using something like Perl or Python over batch files though.